# Upload limit on IAM user policy Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, amazon-iam

I am using cyberduck to upload to Amazon i have it all setup via a IAM user.

It will connect fine and i can upload to the bucket but it will not let me upload anything above 100mb.

Can anyone inform me why here is my IAM policy. It uploads anything under 100mb fine.

```
{
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": ["s3:*"],
                    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::myusers", "arn:aws:s3:::myusers/*"],
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringLike": {
                            "s3:prefix": ["1/*"]
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": ["s3:*"],
                    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::myusers/1/*"]
                }]
            }
```

If i change my policy to a admin policy like below it will upload any filesize fine?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what version of Cyberduck are you using?

Comment: I just successfully uploaded a 167MB file using Cyberduck Version 4.5.2 (15055). Can you describe the error you are experiencing? Or use Jing to capture a video of the problem?

Comment: Hi John are you setup as a IAM user if you setup a IAM user get your keys setup a bucket with a folder and add the policy above see if you can still upload a large file, i am using the latest cyberduck bought from the mac app store.

Comment: video of the issue https://s3bubble.com/share/?file=PFStneery

Comment: That is a really strange issue... Have you tried looking at the policy simulator http://policysim.aws.amazon.com to see if it can shed some light?